# direcrtshow:calll to Renderstream method returns -2147024809

Tags: .net, directshow

I'm building .NET application that uses DirectX API for web camera device rendering. I'm using DirectShowNet Library .

I create an instance of `ICaptureGraphBuilder2` and call `RenderStream`:

```
IBaseFilter target;
...

Guid cat = PinCategory.Still;
Guid med = MediaType.Video;

hr = capGraph.RenderStream(ref PinCategory.Still,   ref med, capFilter, null, target);
hr = capGraph.RenderStream(ref PinCategory.Preview, ref med, capFilter, null, target);
hr = capGraph.RenderStream(ref PinCategory.Capture, ref med, capFilter, null, target);
```

When I call the method `RenderStream` it fails with return code -2147024809:

> 0x80075507  The parameter is incorrect

What about the parameters are incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Error lookup says "-2147024809 = 0x80070057 - The parameter is incorrect." Does PinCategory.Capture work? And try to render to the standard renderer first.

Good luck!